# Is "root access" acceptable in a professional setting in Australian English?

Tags: terminology, offensive-language, computing, australian-english

In Australian English, which has a slang meaning of "root" which is best avoided in a professional setting, is "root access" acceptable in a professional setting?

If not, what synonyms, preferably ones which have a nuance of a Unix OS as opposed to a Windows OS, are more suitable?

Comment: Could you say "superuser access" instead?

Comment: Not my downvote, but surely Australians understand that *root* here is technical terminology and not slang. Else, how would they refer to the subsoil part of a plant, or fractional exponents in mathematics, or the principal note of a musical chord without breaking down in a fit of giggling?

Comment: Most dialects of English have _meat_ as a slang term with (I presume) the same meaning; that doesn't mean you can't refer to the meat-packing district or how they found horse meat in British lasagne.

Comment: @JeremyMiles that feels like having a Windows OS nuance to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "meat-packing district" sounds like an area with lots of nightclubs in it!

Comment: There's almost no limit to the possibilities of linguistic evasiveness or squeamishness if one is determined to go down that path. However, during the past half century, western culture has been steadily ridding itself of that tendency. I think that even if some people's thoughts briefly stray to the sexual connotation of 'root' when they hear the technical term 'root access', they will as quickly dismiss it as being mildly amusing at best, irrelevant at worst. I doubt that anyone would actually take offence at it, or think it in poor taste. As so often, the context makes a huge difference.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Ubuntu uses  superuser  [http://xkcd.com/149/]. Doesn't windows call them administrators?

Comment: @JeremyMiles the XKCD sandwich cartoon doesn't mention "superuser".

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - in some Linux distros, you switch user to root (su root) before doing some action that requires root access. This is dangerous, because you then have root access and might forget. So instead, you prefix the command with sudo - super-user do. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo

Comment: However, I agree with @ErikKowal - to give another example, if you're doing something to do with dog breeding, it's OK to say "bitch". If you're not, it isn't.

Comment: how about taking a dump [of a database]. We used to always joke about that one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Australian English, which has a slang meaning of "root" which is best avoided in a professional setting,

This is not restricted to Australian English. *Root* can mean "penis" Irish English, is attested in British English since the 1840s (and as late as the 21st century) and appears in a Canadian play of the 1970s. It can also mean "copulate with" in Ireland, and I'm sure that applies elsewhere too.

> is "root access" acceptable in a professional setting?

Of course it is. As would any other reference to the concept of *root* in computer science and IT (and there are several such concepts), agriculture, horticulture, along with ways it might be used in every field.

There isn't even the shade of an issue here. If someone sniggers every time they hear the word "root" or can't resist double entendres like "I'd love to give them my root access" in situations where it would not be appropriate, the problem is not with the technical jargon.